# sed: c command, change only the first line, text deleted

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I'm on my second day ever of shell scripting and I've stumbled into this problem: I want to change an entire line of code, which I identify by one word only, and I would like to do that only for the first occurrence.

I'm using sed and the c command, something that looks like this:

Text in file called "prova":

```
Apple is red
Apple is green
Banana
Tangerine
```

`sed` bit of code:

```
sed -i.bak '1,/Apple/c\
Apricot
' prova
```

(I'm using Mac OSX)

Strangely enough, and in agreement with what reported by [these guys](http://wnylug.org/pipermail/users_wnylug.org/2010-May/002382.html), if I do, I get this output for the prova file:

```
Apricot
Banana
Tangerine
```

One "Apple" is gone! Is there a way around this? Please, be patient, I'm a beginner...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly it's a "greedy" match (the _second_ Apple's line, not the first). I don't know enough sed to know for sure, but you might look to see if there's a "non-greedy" modifier for the match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
sed '1cApricot' prova
```

With `1,/Apple/`, you define a range, starting from line 1 and ending at the first occurrence of `Apple` *after* line 1. What you want is not a range, though, just a single line. This can be achieved by only using `1` (instead of e.g. `1,2`).

The above command does work for me, but it depends on the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) version, if it doesn't work, try

```
sed '1c\
Apricot' prova
```

With the `1` you tell [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to change the first line.

If you don't necessarily want to change line 1, but the first occurrence of `Apple`, you can do

```
sed '0,/Apple/s/.*Apple.*/Apricot/'
```

I used the substitute command `s` (frankly, I never use `c`) here and it's only applied to the range starting from line `0` to the first occurrence of `Apple`. If it finds `Apple`, the whole line is replaced with `Apricot`.

Comment: I have tried this command and I get this error:
sed: 1: "1cApricot": command c expects \ followed by text
however, I don't understand it: how do you tell it to change the 'Apple' line as opposed to the 'Banana' line?

Comment: thanks a lot! now it works! But what if I have to change the 'Banana' line? More generally, what if I have to change a line of which I don't know the number - and that I can only identify with a word?

Comment: Edited again. I used the substitute command `s`. I think it's somehow possible to do it with `c`, too, but I don't use it. [tag:sed] gets easily messy, for more advanced stuff I advise to use [tag:awk].

Comment: Slightly shorter version `sed '0,/Apple/s//Apricot/'`

Comment: thanks again for replying! (and your patience!)If I type the last command that you have written, though, I don't get any edits in the file. If I type '1' instead of '0', I get two replacement: can you please explain why? I will soon mark your answer as accepted answer, I would only like to understand more of this first...

Comment: @pfnuesel : might it be that the reason why your last command doesn't work for me is because we use a different sed version?

Comment: You mean the substitute command? I think it should work on any [tag:sed] version, but there are many different flavors of [tag:sed].

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/PatternToFind/PatternToReplaceWith/option'
```

So if you know the workd top find, use it in first part after the `s/` ( PatternToFind`). This is a Reduce Regular Expression so be carefull with char like`*.[(`(and should be escape by`` before) but alphanumeric are explicit.
Replace the (whole) corresponding pattern with the `PatternToReplaceWith` (here only few character like `\&` are special and should be escape by `\`)

You could also make several substitution serialy with a separation by new line or `;`

```
sed 's/Apple/Pie/;s/Banana/Split/;s/Ice/Cream/g' YourFile
```

note the last g that mean *every occurence on the line*.

for first occurence only, you need to load the full file before in buffer before (load each line in holding buffer, at last line recall the buffer in working buffer and make your substitution

```
sed '1h;1!H
$ {x
  s/Apple/Pie/;s/Banana/Split/;s/Ice/Cream/
  }' YourFile
```

Comment: thanks for replying! this doesn't solve the "only change the first occurrence" bit, though...

Comment: I adapt the reply for first occurence ;-)